# Testing Devise updating user registration info with Rspec and getting: ActionController::UnknownFormat: Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I am simply attempting to use the code below to test updating a user's email through a Devise path in an Rspec Request spec and I wish to know why it is giving me the error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat:`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "UsersEdits", type: :request do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it "my test" do
    email = "new@email.com"

    params = { "user[email]" => email, "user[current_password]" => 'foobar' }
    put user_registration_path(user), params

    user.reload
    expect(user.email).to eq(email)
  end
end
```

here is the error:

```
Failure/Error: patch user_registration_path(user), params

 ActionController::UnknownFormat:
   ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just finished tracking this down myself.

`user_registration_path(user)` will generate `"/users.980190962"` which causes that `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error. In some controller setups, you might patch `"/users/980790962"`, but devise just patches `"/users"` directly. I'm guessing devise/warden patches whomever the signed-in user is and doesn't need the user id. So instead:

```
    patch user_registration_path, params: { user: {
      ....
      } }
```

or for rspec:

```
    put user_registration_path, params
```